# How does Depth First-Search visit a node?

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, a-star

An algorithm may come upon a node a second time, i.e. there might be two paths to the node. The algorithm needs to know which path was shorter.

When the Best First Search reaches a node that it has visited before, it is possible that the previous visit  had a longer path. When this happens, the open and closed lists need updating.
This can not happen with an A* search.

Question: Can this happen with a DFS?

The answer is yes, but I thought it was no. Why is it yes? I thought that once a node has been visited it wont go back to it.

Comment: `This can not happen with an A* search.` If heuristic is not optimal then A* will update that node with the cost which is shorter. So A* will manipulate things as well but if heuristic is optimal then it will not because we know there is no other node with cost less.

Answer (score 3):

DFS strategy will visit a node as many times as it finds a path to it. It wouldn't continue visiting from that node down, but it would register the visit itself. This is essential for [DFS edge classification](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7361263/335858).

For example, consider running DFS on this graph:

[image: Graph]

When you reach node `C` for the first time, the path is `A-B-C`. When you reach `C` for the second time, the path is `A-C`, which is shorter.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a graph like this

```
A
|\
B \
|  E
C /
|/
D
```

and traverse it depth-first, from left to right, the following pathes will be visited in that order:

```
A
AB
ABC
ABCD
AE
AED
```

You see, the first visit of D is on a longer path (ABCD) than the second one (AED).